# Rails Syntax highlighter albino is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-highlighting

I  am using syntax highlighter "albino" i my rails project ,but it is not displaying any thing

below i have written the code

in helper model

```
def highlight(text)
  Albino.new(text, :ruby)
end
```

In the view

```
<% @codes.each do |code| %>
  <%= highlight(code) %>
<% end %>
```

so can any one help me where i am going wrong
 or suggest any good highlighter gem for rails?

Comment: Can you just confirm exactly what the symptom is? Are you seeing an error, or just 'nothing' in the response? Have you checked that 'code' actually has what you expect in it? (i.e. take the highlight call out, and see if you get non-highlighted text)

Comment: it is showing nothing .when i remove highlight call i am getting non-highlighted text .

Comment: I can confirm that Albino.colorize is always returning an empty string (Rails v3.2, ruby 1.9.3).

Answer (score 0):

Which errors do you get?

You are missing a `.` after @codes:

```
<% @codes.each do |code| %>
  <%= highlight(code) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to write this here but in my code i have written it correctly . i have edited my question now

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your helper is creating a new Albino instance but not using actually asking it to syntax highlight.

Change your helper as follows:

```
def highlight(text)
  Albino.colorize(text, :ruby)
end
```

Comment: ... or maybe not. Just noticed the docs cite exactly what you've done as OK as the library adds a to_s method on the Albino object. Weird :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)? It's the syntax highlighter used on both Google Code and Stack Overflow, which is likely to mean it's reasonably robust.

I don't normally like putting too much functionality in JavaScript, but it seems to me that syntax highlighting is a reasonable feature to add in this way - after all the code will still be readable without the highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an old problem, but I just came across it myself.

The problem is that Albino is outputting HTML directly as it's being parsed (I think that's the right word, I'm quite new to this).

For example:

```
highlight(text)
```

And text is:

```
def hello_world
  puts "Hello World!".to_s
end
```

Will result in:

```
<div class="highlight"><pre><span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">hello_world</span> <span class="nb">puts</span> <span class="s2">&quot;Hello World!&quot;</span><span class="o">.</span><span class="n">to_s</span> <span class="k">end</span> </pre> </div>
```

What needs to be done is add .html_safe into your highlight method.

```
Albino.colorize(text).html_safe
```

That should work.